# Fastest way to disconnect client in Net::Server

Tags: perl

I have some scripts which must be fast as possible (used as mpd5 up/down scripts).

Have the idea: lets this script send arguments to some tcp server and finish work, and then the server works hard and long.

This is my test server script with Net::Server :

```
use Net::Server::PreForkSimple;
use base "Net::Server::PreForkSimple";

  sub process_request {
     my $self=shift;
     my $a=<STDIN>;
     close STDIN; close STDOUT; #trying to disconect client here
     $self->log(1,"start $a");
     sleep 50;
     $self->log(1,"finish $a");
      }
__PACKAGE__->run(port => 2000);
```

Problem is : i dont know how to disconect client on line after $a=.
Client script waiting all this "sleep 50".
I am trying close STD* but its doesnt help.
Also I cant locate any close or disconect method in docs of this Net::Server.

Can anyone point me to right direction?

UPD:

```
close($self->{server}->{client});
```

doesnt work too.

I test this by

```
echo test | nc 127.0.0.1 2000
```

and this command is working 50 sec.

But i want nc closed immediately after send "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i posted this Q on rt.cpan.org , i get a answer:

right code with fast disconnect is:

```
use base "Net::Server::PreForkSimple";

sub process_request {
    my $self = shift;
    my $a = <STDIN>;
    $self->post_process_request;
    $self->log(1,"start $a");
    sleep 50;
    $self->log(1,"finish $a");
}
__PACKAGE__->run(port => 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$self->post_process_request` method to execute code after closing the connection.

```perl
use Net::Server::PreForkSimple;
use base "Net::Server::PreForkSimple";

sub process_request {
    my $self=shift;
    my $a=<STDIN>;
}

sub post_process_request {
    $self->log(1,"start $a");
    sleep 50;
    $self->log(1,"finish $a");
}
```

But keep in mind that the request handling child process will still be unavailable for 50 seconds, so this might not be the right solution for you if you want to process many requests as fast as possible, because you might run out of children processes to handle these requests. In this case I'd suggest a message queue like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) or [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/).

Comment: I start server with you code, and run in console: echo test | nc 127.0.0.1 2000 , result is -> no disconnection until nc timeout. Looks like not important is it process_req or post_process

Comment: I solve problem by use Directory:Queue. Its another way, but its work. Thanks for point me to message queue

Answer (score 0):

The post_process_request is a good answer - but to shut down the client connection you would need to first call SUPER::post_process_request since that is where the client handle gets shut down.  The better answer would be to throw that code in the post_client_connection_hook which handles after the client is all gone.

```
sub process_request {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{'a'} = <STDIN>;
}

sub post_client_connection_hook {
    my $self = shift;
    my $a = $self->{'a'};
    $self->log(1,"start $a");
    sleep 50;
    $self->log(1,"finish $a");
}
```